# Constructing $A(\neq I_n) \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$ with $A^{n+1} = I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I want to find $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$ not equal to identity matrix such that $A^{n+1} = I_n$.

---

From my previous post, [$A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Q})$ with $A\neq I_n$, $A^p=I_n$ then $p\leq n+1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373791)

Followings are my trials:

Note that the matrix equation gives $t^{n+1} - 1$, but since $t^{n+1} -1 = (t-1) (1+t+t^2+ \cdots + t^{n-1})$. Note that minimal polynomial divides this and since $m_A(t) \neq t-1$, it divides $(1+t+\cdots + t^{n-1})$. But this can be reducible ...

Comment: Have you  heard of Rational Canonical Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $p(t)=t^{n+1}-1=(t-1) (1+t+t^2+\dots+t^n)$.

Consider the companion matrix of $\chi(t)=1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^n$. It is
$$A_n=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & -1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
It means its characteristic polynomial is $\chi$. By Cayley-Hamilton's theorem, we get $p(A_n) =(A_n-I_n) \cdot \chi(A_n)=(A_n-I_n)\cdot O_n=O_n$, e. g.
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}^3=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0%2C+-1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+-1%7D%7D%5E3